# How can I add a frame around parts of my document?

Tags: templates

I want to add frame around parts of my document. Example from (https://hobsonresearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/responseletter_hacks.pdf) in page 5:

[image]

How can I do similiar example? I was not able to figure out which `documentclass`, `font` they are using.

---

Original code taken from https://zenkelab.org/resources/latex-rebuttal-response-to-reviewers-template/

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % to generate some filler text
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newcounter{reviewer}
\setcounter{reviewer}{0}
\newcounter{point}[reviewer]
\setcounter{point}{0}

% This refines the format of how the reviewer/point reference will appear.
\renewcommand{\thepoint}{P\,\thereviewer.\arabic{point}}

% command declarations for reviewer points and our responses
\newcommand{\reviewersection}{\stepcounter{reviewer} \bigskip \hrule
    \section*{Reviewer \thereviewer}}

\newenvironment{reply}
{\medskip \noindent \begin{sf}\textbf{Reply}:\  }
    {\medskip \end{sf}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Response to the reviewers}
% General intro text goes here
We thank the reviewers for their critical assessment of our work.
In the following we address their concerns point by point.

% Let's start point-by-point with Reviewer 1
\reviewersection

% Point one description
\begin{quote}
    \lipsum[1]
    \label{pt:foo}
\end{quote}

% Our reply
\begin{reply}
    We agree with the reviewer on this important point. This is what we did to
    fix it.
    \lipsum[2]
\end{reply}

\begin{quote}
    Reviewer \thereviewer's second point.
    \label{pt:bar}
\end{quote}

\begin{reply}
    And our reply to it.
\end{reply}

\reviewersection

\begin{quote}
    This is the first point of Reviewer \thereviewer. With some more words foo
    bar foo bar ...
\end{quote}

\begin{reply}
    Our reply to it with reference to one of our points above using the \LaTeX's
    label/ref system (see also \ref{pt:foo}).
\end{reply}

\end{document}
```

Output , where boxes does not show up:

[image]

Comment: Surely this doesn't need a particular document class. You could use a plain `\fbox` for the comments or if you need something fancier, you use the `framed` package or one of the TikZ based box packages `tcolorbox` for example. But that seems like overkill for this use.

Comment: Some people use `\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}` could it be use as well, it adds small beginning of the box though? It also does not work with `\documentclass[11pt]{article}` :-(

Comment: `article` should be fine.  Could you show us some example code that you think should work but doesn't?  Your first link provides several code snippets and a link to a tex template, your second link is blocked, and your third link doesn't seem related to "a box around the response".  Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: @Teepeemm please see my updated answer, I have shared what I have tried using `\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}` inside `article `.

Comment: @alper your code does not compile

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz sorry, I have fixed the small bug

Comment: @alper Please edit your question title to reflect which latex problem you are trying to solve instead of the content problem. Future users, who would like to add a frame around parts of their document, will have a hard time finding your question with its current title. They won't care if you are replying to reviewers or write your diary .

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz You are right and thanks I fixed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `tcolorbox` package to either redefine the `quote` environment (which you already use) or define a new environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % to generate some filler text
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\newcounter{reviewer}
\setcounter{reviewer}{0}
\newcounter{point}[reviewer]
\setcounter{point}{0}

% This refines the format of how the reviewer/point reference will appear.
\renewcommand{\thepoint}{P\,\thereviewer.\arabic{point}}

% command declarations for reviewer points and our responses
\newcommand{\reviewersection}{\stepcounter{reviewer} \bigskip \hrule
    \section*{Reviewer \thereviewer}}

\newcommand{\shortpoint}[1]{\refstepcounter{point}  \bigskip \noindent
    {\textbf{Reviewer~Point~\thepoint} } ---~#1\par }

\newenvironment{reply}
{\medskip \noindent \begin{sf}\textbf{Reply}:\  }
    {\medskip \end{sf}}

\newcommand{\shortreply}[2][]{\medskip \noindent \begin{sf}\textbf{Reply}:\  #2
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{ \hfill \footnotesize (#1)}%
        \medskip \end{sf}}
        
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\renewtcolorbox{quote}{sharp corners,colback=white}

\begin{document}

\section*{Response to the reviewers}
% General intro text goes here
We thank the reviewers for their critical assessment of our work.
In the following we address their concerns point by point.

% Let's start point-by-point with Reviewer 1
\reviewersection

% Point one description
\begin{quote}
%    \begin{point}
        \lipsum[1]
        \label{pt:foo}
%    \end{point}
\end{quote}

% Our reply
\begin{reply}
    We agree with the reviewer on this important point. This is what we did to
    fix it.
    \lipsum[2]
\end{reply}

\begin{quote}
%    \begin{point}
        Reviewer \thereviewer's second point.
        \label{pt:bar}
%    \end{point}
\end{quote}

\begin{reply}
    And our reply to it.
\end{reply}

\reviewersection

\begin{quote}
%    \begin{point}
        This is the first point of Reviewer \thereviewer. With some more words foo
        bar foo bar ...
%    \end{point}
\end{quote}

\begin{reply}
    Our reply to it with reference to one of our points above using the \LaTeX's
    label/ref system (see also \ref{pt:foo}).
\end{reply}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If possible, inside `\begin{quote}...\end{quote}` , can we have new-line between paragraphs? I have tried `\newline` but it did not work.

Comment: "did not work" is not a useful problem description. If you have a new question, ask a new question including a MWE